# Split string into list of string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which is 28000 lines long and is laid out like below:

```
List<string> sQuerys = new List<string>();

string FullFileQuery = " EXEC spDataCache_INS_XSCDV1P @Company = 'UKC                                ', @Country = 'AE                                 ', @Trade_Lane = 'ARABIAN GULF/MIDDLE EAST           ', @Trade_Region = 'INDIA/PAKISTAN/MIDDLE EAST         '
EXEC spDataCache_INS_XSCDV1P @Company = 'UKC                                ', @Country = 'AL                                 ', @Trade_Lane = 'MEDITERRANEAN                      ', @Trade_Region = 'EUROPE/MEDITERRANEAN               '
EXEC spDataCache_INS_XSCDV1P @Company = 'UKC                                ', @Country = 'AO                                 ', @Trade_Lane = 'WEST AFRICA                        ', @Trade_Region = 'AFRICA                             '
EXEC spDataCache_INS_XSCDV1P @Company = 'UKC                                ', @Country = 'AR                                 ', @Trade_Lane = 'EAST COAST SOUTH AMERICA           ', @Trade_Region = 'LATIN AMERICA                      '
EXEC spDataCache_INS_XSCDV1P @Company = 'UKC                                ', @Country = 'AU                                 ', @Trade_Lane = 'AUSTRALIA/NEW ZEALAND              ', @Trade_Region = 'FAR EAST AND OCEANIA               '"
```

I want to split the string every 15000th line and add to my list of string `sQuerys`.

So the 28000 lines will be split into 15000 lines and 13000 lines and added to the list. I am unsure on the quickest way to achieve this.

EDIT:

The code I have tried doing but I am stuck is below:

```
if (FullFileQuery.Split('\n').Length > 15000)
{
    //28000
    int numLines = FullFileQuery.Split('\n').Length;
    //LOOP TWICE.
    for (int i = 0; i < ((numLines / 15000) + 1); i++)
    {
        //NEED TO ADD TO sQuerys in here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit unclear. Is this from a file? What kind of list are you adding the 15k and 13k lines to? What's your definition of "quickest" - highest performance or least code?

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? Please edit your post with the Code you tried, then we will / could help you. SO is not a Code writing service!

Comment: @stuartd Sorry for being unclear. I have tried to edit my question. I want to add to a List<string> and the highest performance because there may be 200000 lines and i have to split into chunks of 15000 lines.

Comment: @Torben I have added the code that I tried. The reason I didn't add the code is because I didn't think it was the most efficient.

Comment: well, instead of making a string of "fullfilequery" and adding a bajillion lines to it. make it a list, and add each query as a line...

Comment: @BugFinder And then what .. Look at the list that has 28000 rows and join the strings every 15000 row?

Comment: What do you plan to do with those 15000 line strings ?

Comment: @ClémentPicou They will be CommandText and Executed to SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Skip` and `Take` Linq methods to do something like this:

```
int chunkSize = 15000;
var splitted = FullFileQuery.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int chunks=splitted.Length/chunkSize; //Get number of chunks 

for (int i=0;i<chunks;i++)
{                
    sQuerys.Add(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,splitted
                            .Skip(i * chunkSize) //skip the already added lines
                            .Take(chunkSize))); //take the new lines
}
```

So basically first we split all the lines into `splitted`. Then we divide that splitted array length by the chunk size we want to get how many chunks are we going to get. Finally, we loop this number of chunks first using `Skip` to "jump" the lines we already added to the previous chunks and then `Take` to take the chunk.

Haven't tried it so comment if there is something not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = @"your long multiline string...";

        var list = new List<string>();
        var lines = input.Split('\n');
        var index = 0;
        var batchSize = 15000;
        while (index < lines.Count())
        {
            list.Add(string.Join(string.Empty, lines.Skip(index).Take(batchSize)));
            index += batchSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This extension method will batch any type of list into an `IEnumerable` of batches.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
{
    var batch = new List<T>(batchSize);

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        batch.Add(item);

        if (batch.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return batch;
            batch = new List<T>(batchSize);
        }
    }

    if (batch.Any())
    {
        yield return batch;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var batchesOfLines = allLines.Batch(15000);
```