# How do I create a linq statement to take a list of items and break them into groups of 50 each

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of this custom class and I'm trying to find out how to use a linq statement in C# to break that list into groups of 50 items each. Any ideas?

```
List<Symbol> symbolList = new List<Symbol>();

public class Symbol
    {
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string Market { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Not specifically Linq but https://stackoverflow.com/a/43607422/43846

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/Wee-Projects/LinqExtensions/blob/master/src/Wee.LinqExtensions/PageExtension.cs

Comment: `Take` and `Skip` might help.

Comment: Well, you can use `GroupBy` but **1:** Unfortunatly, you should copy the result to `List/Array` etc **2:** It looks a few difficult for understanding `List<int> list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(2, 249)); int count = 0; int groupNumber = 1;  var test = list.GroupBy(item => count++ < 50 ? groupNumber : groupNumber += (count = 1)).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built in LINQ method for creating batches, however there's an awesome community maintained project called [MoreLinq](https://morelinq.github.io/) that contains a [.Batch](https://morelinq.github.io/2.6/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Batch__1.htm) extension as well as all kinds of other helpful extensions.

```
var batched = symbolList.Batch(50); // returns IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Symbol>> 
// Where each collection contains 50 items
```